# Pulseaudio: can't loopback sink.monitor into soundcard speakers

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to  loopback the sink.monitor of a null-sink into my soundcard speakers but It doesn't work: no sound coming out from the speakers. The null-sink (appoutput) is fed from VLC (this works, I can see the sliders move in pavucontrol). (I'm using Ubuntu 18.04).

Here is the code I have:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=appoutput
PULSE_SINK=appoutput vlc& #start VLC and direct ouput onto the sink created 
#This is what doesn't work ?
pactl load-module module-loopback  source=appoutput.source sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

A partial listing of pactl list sinks is:

```
Sink #0
    State: IDLE
    Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
    Description: Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 7
    Mute: no
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed..., the command 
`pactl load-module module-loopback  source=appoutput.source sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`

should be after substituting `appoutput.monitor` for `appoutput.source`:

`pactl load-module module-loopback  source=appoutput.monitor sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`

and then the loopback module doesn't fail to initialize.